# JavaScript Unicode standard format

Tags: javascript, json, unicode, unicode-escapes

Is there any standard on how to write Unicode characters in JavaScript/JSON?
For instance, is there any difference between `\u011b` and `\u011B`? Most of the web examples use second format. Also, there is an option for ASCII characters to be written in a short format like `\xe1`. Which format is preferable (standard). Is it good practice to mix these formats together and what about performance?

Comment: \xe1 is not valid in JSON (and it's ISO 8859-1, not ASCII). Writing the character as the character works just fine, too.

Answer (score 1):

For the first question: both version are valid. It is more a coding convention, you should prefer what convention is already used in your files/project. Then check on your community (convention used by other programs you heavily use, what they prefer, and as last option you can choose one way. But in any case, keep consistent.

Personally I prefer none of them for code: UTF-8 is so wide used and browsers should understand it, so I would put directly the right character (as character, not as escape sequence). If codepoint is important, I would add it into a comment. it is expected that all developers and tools will have UTF-8 editors.

Javascript uses UCS-2, so the precursor of UTF-16, but considering unicode code points to be just 16bit length (so some emoji would use two characters).

The byte format should not be used for text: it hides the meaning. There are exceptions: e.g. to check which encoding you get from user, or if you have BOM. [But so just for signatures]. For other binary cases, it is ok to use `\x1e` escapes, e.g. for key identification.

Note: you should really follow one coding guidelines. Google for it and you will find many, e.g. this from Google (which is maybe too much): https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html

Comment: "If codepoint is important, I would add it into a comment.", unfortunately, there is no explicit comment syntax in JSON.

Comment: @Pac0: right, I forget about JSON. OTOH often JSON is just a transport and so in original code one could add comment. [or for configuration file the "_field_note" field could be used (but ugly, so useable only on very important comments). I'll add the JSON tag to the question, not to miss that point